# Linux: What is the encoding of this shell script?

Tags: linux, encoding

I'm trying to determine the encoding of a shell script. The following "file" command returns "application/x-shellscript". Is this the actual encoding? I was expecting a standard encoding such as "utf-8" or "ascii". What am I missing?

```
file --mime test.sh
test.sh: application/x-shellscript
```

EDIT: I moved the file over to my macbook and it worked:

```
file --mime test.sh
test.sh: text/x-shellscript; charset=us-ascii
```

Comment: What are the permissions of the file?

Comment: Shell scripts don't really have an encoding, per se -- they're just a sequence of shell commands. These commands may include text in any encoding, any *combination* of encodings, or even just raw binary data.

Comment: -rwxrwxr-x on the original machine. -rwxr-xr-x on the macbook.

Comment: @imagineerThis Note that OS X often uses outdated/old/different/forked-by-Apple versions of some common Unix utilities, and CoreUtils isn't an exception. It may be the case that the `file` command on your Linux differs from that on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `--mime-encoding` switch:

```
file --mime-encoding test.sh
```

Comment: switch wasn't available on the original machine I ran "file", but works on my macbook.

Comment: God, I hope I don't get flagged for serial upvoting, but you are always there when I read any question!

Comment: @imagineerThis what flavor of linux are you using specifically?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Hehe, thanks :) No, serial upvoting does not deserve a flag, since it's not offensive, but I think it's also reverted automagically at midnight, just like serial `vote--`.